# Filter and sort by a calculated column using case (column not found)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to filter and sort by a calculated column using case but I'm getting a syntax error.

> Column difference_sum and column payments_sum not found

I need to be able to have a WHERE and ORDER BY clause.

I have two tables 'contracts' and 'payments'.

**Contracts** table

```
+----+-----------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | contract_number | legal_sum | bonus_sum |
+----+-----------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |    110258465651 |        50 |        20 |
|  2 |    564984656355 |        15 |        12 |
|  3 |    548498415165 |       150 |        35 |
+----+-----------------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Payments** table

```
+----+--------------+----------+
| id | contract_id  | paid_sum |
+----+--------------+----------+
|  1 | 564984656355 |        7 |
|  2 | 564984656355 |        1 |
|  3 | 564984656355 |        2 |
+----+--------------+----------+
```

1. First I need to calculate the difference between legal sum and bonus sum (difference_sum)
2. Then I need to get the sum of payments.paid_sum (payments_sum)
3. Then I need to sort by the criteria if (payments_sum - difference_sum <= 0)

So I made this query but it says that difference_sum does not exist:

```
SELECT
    (contracts.legal_sum - contracts.bonus_sum) as difference_sum
    sum(payments.paid_sum) as payments_sum,
    CASE
        WHEN (difference_sum - payments_sum) <= 0 THEN "All paid"
        WHEN (difference_sum - payments_sum) > 0 THEN "Not paid"
    END AS isPaid
FROM contracts
INNER JOIN payments on contracts.id = payments.contract_id
WHERE isPaid = "All paid"
ORDER BY isPaid
```

**Example output:**

```
+----------------+--------------+----------+
| difference_sum | payments_sum |  isPaid  |
+----------------+--------------+----------+
|             30 |           30 | All paid |
|             48 |           15 | Not paid |
|            100 |          100 | All paid |
+----------------+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample table data and also specify the expected result. BTW, looks like you need a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do here, you have a SUM without a GROUP BY

Comment: I'm trying to sort by isPaid (yes I forgot to add GROUP BY). But it does not allow me to sort it this way.

Comment: Please add sample data that match (id/contracts_id) and expected output. Should contract_id match contract_number?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Added example output. conctract_id mathces contracts.id

Comment: You can't reference the alias `difference_sum` in the same select list where it was introduced. Need one more  external `select from (select .. ` or just replace it with expression

Comment: @Serg how could I do an external query?

Comment: "conctract_id mathces contracts.id", then your sample data makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT difference_sum, payments_sum, isPaid 
FROM (
    SELECT  payments_sum,
        (contracts.legal_sum - contracts.bonus_sum) as difference_sum
        CASE
            WHEN (contracts.legal_sum - contracts.bonus_sum - payments_sum) <= 0 THEN "All paid"
            WHEN (contracts.legal_sum - contracts.bonus_sum - payments_sum) > 0 THEN "Not paid"
        END AS isPaid
    FROM contracts
    INNER JOIN ( 
       SELECT contract_id, sum(payments.paid_sum) as payments_sum
       FROM payments 
       GROUP BY contract_id
    ) payments on contracts.id = payments.contract_id
) q
WHERE isPaid = "All paid"
-- why order by a single value ?
-- ORDER BY isPaid
```

Probably you also need to add contract_id column to make it more useful.

Comment: Yes, thank you! That's what I was looking for but didn't know how to do!